# Why is this countable union of closed sets closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm having trouble understanding the logic of the following statement (taken from pg 53 of Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Space by Frank Jones):

"Though unions of countably many closed sets are not necessarily closed, in this case it is easy to check that $F$ is closed. For any limit of $F$ must already be a limit point of some finite union $\bigcup_{k=1}^N K_k$, and the latter is closed."

Definitions:
$A$ is a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $E_k$ is defined as
$$
E_k = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: k-1\leq |x| \leq k\}
$$
$K_k$ are compact sets and $G_k$ open sets satisfying
\begin{align*}
K_k \subset A \cap E_k \subset G_k \\
\lambda(G_k \setminus K_k) < \epsilon 2^{-k}
\end{align*} 
$\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure, and $F = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty K_k$.

Comment: Hint: are any of the $K_k$'s disjoint?

Comment: the union of any locally finite family of closed sets is closed. Please let me know if you need more details. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_finite_collection#Closed_sets

Comment: Got it, thanks!